# Video Chat implement with h264 encoder

Tags: android, video, encoder

Hi guys I am trying to develop a video chat application and I am using the h264 encoder for video, but I am facing some issues as the video seems a bit unclear. I have attached an image below in which you can see some shade above the eyebrows. Can anybody tell me what could be the possible problem? Because it occurs only with the front camera and works fine with the real camera.[image]

Hoping for response.

Comment: The front camera on any Android device is usually pretty bad, so this sounds more like a hardware issue.

Comment: No i checked with many devices and other applications too. Example tango don't have that issue.

Comment: Is this image the raw camera image? Or the result after encoding in H.264? And if so, which encoder are you using?

Comment: I am capturing the YUV data using Camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer by implementing the on onPreviewFrame and passing it to JNI which in-turn processes this data and send the data to the remote ip provided. And on the remote side the data is drawn to GLSurface view.

Comment: Try to process some video from, for example, youtube - it helps you to check it is h.264 or a hardware bug.

Answer (score 2):

The encoding world is literally huge, there are a lot of ways to store data, manipulate data and transfer data, and when this comes to the imaging world all the options simply multiply.

Your problem reminds me [this topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling), also looks like there are some shadows, kinda like that bluish shadow is part of a previous frame with a shape in a different position.

Remember that H264 is a patented codec and you have to pay for it if you want to use it.